# Three answers disappeared

Tags: support, answers, deletion

Yesterday I have 287 answers in my profile, today 284. I don't know which answers disappeared, the only thing I can say is that I lost some reputation in functional analysis tag. What has happened? I often put a lot of efforts in my answers, so I don't want them to be deleted without my permission.

Comment: :Same thing has happened with me. I do not know exactly what's going on.

Comment: Heh. This happened to me today, too. I can live with a minor reputation hit, but it's still *very* irritating.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170277/definition-of-fractional-derivative-integral) of deleting a post of mine by some users of this website without my permission.

Comment: @Mhenni, the person asked whether one could define X as YZW, and you noted that there are already perfectly good definitions of X. That doesn't actually answer the question, so its deletion should not come as a surprise.

Comment: There seems to be a recent epidemic of disappearances. Is there some sort of explanation of that?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, perhaps this is worth a meta question.

Comment: I think the reason is that LVK has deleted his account. It is a big sorrow - he contributed this site a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An account was deleted. This deletes questions with a negative vote total, so deletes the corresponding answers.

For future reference, here is a relevant section of the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) (emphasis added):

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, **modify**, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.

Comment: Could you tell which answers were deleted?

Comment: I don't know. I looked through some of your deleted answers but they all seem to have been deleted by you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking time

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth a feature request that questions with a negative vote total be retained if they have _answers_ with positive score.

Comment: Do 15K users have the ability to see such deleted questions (and the associated answers)?  I couldn't find them.

Comment: They have the ability to _see_ them, but whether they have the ability to _find_ them is another matter...

Answer (score 13):

I agree Henning Makholm that if a question got an answer with a positive score, it will stay on the website independently of the score of the question. It's not for the reputation points, [image]

even if I lost a lot of points, as it's just an arbitrary quantity.

The major problem is that for example we provide a long answer, or we spent a lot of time to think on it or type it, and there will be no trace of it. A good thing would be to upvote the question, but sometimes we can forget, or don't give the upvote because there was something unclear in the question (and in this case we wait for a clarification, but it may never come, or latter but we don't see it).

Comment: Alas, this is one of many poor design decisions in the SE software. We also lose many valuable votes when a user is deleted. That is why I always try to encourage users to consider actions other than deletion. Unfortunately that does not always work (and not all moderators support such efforts).

Comment: This decision of SE design makes me mad!

Answer (score 2):

273 points this time!  Several accounts were deleted in the past couple of weeks, costing me 10 or 15 or so points each time.  It must have been quite a prolific poster.  But the poster's identity is secret, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just got dinked for 86 points because of a deleted user or users.  It came in two stages, a -56, which then got incremented to -86.